# Logit Laplace Loss Function

Tags: logistic, loss-functions, laplace-distribution

In a recent OpenAi paper, the authors propose a novel loss function for the reconstruction term of a VAE coined Logit-Laplace loss. They detail the math on page 13 of the paper but I am having trouble understanding it. First of all, this seems to be something else than the [Log-Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-Laplace_distribution) and I dont understand how applying a sigmoid to a Laplace distribution results in the expression given in equation 2. Also I dont get what exact operation they mean with logit. I tried to put that piece of math down in python but get NaN errors.

Apparently also they take the logarithm of equation 2 without giving a reason for that.

Maybe someone can clarify things a bit ? would be much appreciated...

[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit.  If you get NaNs for $x\in(0,1)$ then either $x$ is *extremely* close to $0$ or $1$ or you have an error in your code. For explanations of transforming distributions, with many examples, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform+random+variable+distribution. You can narrow this search to review [examples involving the logit transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform+random+variable+distribution+logit).

Comment: _Why do they take the log?_ It’s common to optimize log-likelihood instead of likelihood. The practical reason for this is computer precision; there’s a limit to how small of a real number a computer can approximate, before it just gets treated as 0. Optimizing in log-space avoids this. Instead of $10^{-100}$, we just store $-100$ (assuming base 10 log).